# Calling a function in one container from another Container

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have the mainViewController.swift which has 2 embedded containers. I need to cause a button in `container1` to change its label when I press a button in `container2`.

The following `my poor invention` code in container2ViewController did not cut it.

```
((self.MainController as! ViewController).container1 as! Container1ViewController).yesBt.setTitle("Exit", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

I get the yellow triangle on the left margin and message saying:
"*cast from UIView to unrelated type Continer1ViewController always fails*"

There must be a better way to do this, I hope.

Comment: To make it easier for answerers, or others with similar problems, please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: @Mayank Patel We edit thanks messages out of posts rather than in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send messages between objects that aren't directly connected, you can use NSNotification.  Your container that needs to change listens for the notification, which is posted by your other container when it's button is tapped.